# Route set switching per request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am working on upgrading existing rails 2.3.8 app to rails 3.2.7. The issue is with the routing since in old (2.3.x ) version there were multiple route sets being initialized on application startup and then "swapped" depending on request domain. The new rails 3 routing was mostly rewritten and I am not sure if it is possible at all to implement "dynamic" route set switching per request. I will appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: Can you post some or all of the Rails 2.3 `config/routes.rb` file, and an example of how you were "switching" the route sets per request?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [request-based route constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints).